# How can I create a MARKET order with SL/TP in Bybit using CCXT?

Tags: python, trading, ccxt

I need to make this code works for MARKET orders, I can't find how to get it.

```
exchange.create_order(
   symbol='ADA/USDT:USDT',
   type='market',
   side='sell',
   amount=60,
   params={
       'leverage': 1,
       'stopLossPrice': SL_PRICE,
       'takeProfitPrice': TP_PRICE,
   },
)
```